How to create a contextual menu in Window Explorer using a PNG file as a shortcut to launching another file type of the same name?
A folder contain hundreds of    FileName.png    images.
Another folder contain as many corresponding FileName.pad which is opened by a particular application, called Pad_Designer.exe.
I need a way to utilize the FineName.png image as a shortcut to launch Pad_Designer.exe with its corresponding DataFile.pad.
I am thinking to implement a « RightClick » option in Window Explorer to add a menu choice to launch the DataFile.pad through Designer.exe.
Because the FileName.png is the same name as its corresponding FileName.pad, it should be possible to associate the Pad_Designer.exe with the proper DataFile.pad.
OP: 20449316 present many options but none that will manage the switch from a png file to a pad file type.  I found some ways to add a context menu in Window Explorer but the particularity of my application is that the FileName.png is not a FileName.pad file, so a contextual menu will not select the proper Pad_Designer.exe app .
What is needed is some strategy to call the *.pad file identified by the *.png filename.
I suspect I must build a small executable to launch the proper app but I don’t know how to proceed further. I have a limited experience in coding but if I know where to start I probably can manage further.
Thanks for any help and suggestions.
